# External SVG icons do not load properly in Internet Explorer 11 with snap.svg.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to help a designer friend fix the issue with snap.svg.js plugin and internet explorer 11 on a site that someone else developed, and I need some help with it because I suck at javascript and jquery. Apparently external svg icons are not being loaded properly in IE11.

There is a testimonials section on the page:

```
<div class="fw-gray hp-testimonials">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 center">
      <div id="matic-tec" class="svg-container"></div>
      <p>Quisque felis odio, dictum id tellus posuere, fringilla bibendum ligula.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 center">
      <div id="bechtle" class="svg-container"></div>
      <p>Quisque felis odio, dictum id tellus posuere, fringilla bibendum ligula.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 center">
      <div id="mars-solutions" class="svg-container"></div>
      <p>Quisque felis odio, dictum id tellus posuere, fringilla bibendum ligula.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 center">
      <div id="fkonline" class="svg-container"></div>
      <p>Quisque felis odio, dictum id tellus posuere, fringilla bibendum ligula.</p>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- container -->
</div> <!-- fw-gray -->
```

Then the SVG icons are appended to the empty divs with the class "svg-container" and their own unique id's through jquery.

```
var msBlackText, msRedText;
var bGreenBack, bWhiteText;
var mColor;
var fkBlue, fkYellow;
var animationSpeed = 100;
var marsSolutionContainer = Snap('#mars-solutions');
var marsSolutionSVG = Snap.load("/img/svg/logo-mars-solutions.svg", function(f) {
    msBlackText = f.selectAll('#marssolutions-svg-blacktext path');
    msRedText = f.selectAll('#marssolutions-svg-redtext path')
    msBlackText.attr({fill: 'rgba(102,102,102,0.5)'});
    msRedText.attr({fill: 'rgba(102,102,102,0.5)'});
    marsSolutionContainer.append(f);
});
var bechtleContainer = Snap('#bechtle');
var bechtleSVG = Snap.load("/img/svg/logo-bechtle.svg", function(f) {
    bGreenBack = f.selectAll(".greenColor");
    bWhiteText = f.selectAll(".whiteText");
    bechtleOff();
    bechtleContainer.append(f);
});
var maticTecContainer = Snap('#matic-tec');
var maticTecSVG = Snap.load("/img/svg/logo-matic-tec.svg", function(f) {
    mColor = f.selectAll("path");
    mtecOff();
    maticTecContainer.append(f);
});
var fkOnlineContainer = Snap('#fkonline');
var fkOnlineSVG = Snap.load("/img/svg/logo-fkonline.svg", function(f) {
    fkblue = f.selectAll('#blue path, #blue polygon');
    fkYellow = f.selectAll('#yellow path');
    fkoOff();
    fkOnlineContainer.append(f);
});


// Hover Hnadler
// Testimonials
$('.hp-testimonials .col-md-3').hover(
        function() {
                $(this).find('p').css('color', 'rgba(102,102,102,1)');
                $(this).find('a').css('color', 'rgba(102,102,102,1)');
        var company = $(this).find(".svg-container").attr('id');
        switch(company) {
            case "matic-tec":
                mtecOn();
                break;
            case "bechtle":
                bechtleOn();
                break;
            case "mars-solutions":
                marsOn();
                break;
            case "fkonline":
                fkoOn();
                break;
        }
        },
        function() {
                $(this).find('p').css('color', 'rgba(102,102,102,0.5)');
                $(this).find('a').css('color', 'rgba(102,102,102,0.5)');
                grayOn();
        }
)

function mtecOn() {
    mColor.animate({fill: '#046296'}, animationSpeed);
}
function mtecOff() {
    mColor.animate({fill: 'rgba(180,180,180,0.5)'}, animationSpeed);
}
function bechtleOn() {
    bGreenBack.animate({fill: '#008C58'}, animationSpeed);
        bWhiteText.animate({fill: '#fff'}, animationSpeed);
}
function bechtleOff () {
    bGreenBack.animate({fill: 'rgba(180,180,180,0.5)'}, animationSpeed);
        bWhiteText.animate({fill: '#f6f6f6'}, animationSpeed);
}
function marsOn() {
    msBlackText.animate({fill: '#373F43'}, animationSpeed);
        msRedText.animate({fill: '#A50931'}, animationSpeed);
}
function marsOff() {
    msBlackText.animate({fill: 'rgba(180,180,180,0.5)'}, animationSpeed);
        msRedText.animate({fill: 'rgba(180,180,180,0.5)'}, animationSpeed);
}
function fkoOn() {
    fkblue.animate({fill: '#005CA8'}, animationSpeed);
        fkYellow.animate({fill: '#FFCA00'}, animationSpeed);
}
function fkoOff() {
    fkblue.animate({fill: 'rgba(180,180,180,0.5)'}, animationSpeed);
        fkYellow.animate({fill: '#f6f6f6'}, animationSpeed);
}
function grayOn() {
        mtecOff();
        bechtleOff();
        marsOff();
        fkoOff();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.svg-container').animate({
        'opacity': '1'
    });
})
```

SVG icons load properly in all major browsers except IE11 and below.
In IE11, only the empty svg tag is being loaded. 
I googled around and I found [here](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/206) that other people also faced the same issue with this plugin. I tried changing "Snap.load" in variables with $('#mars-solutions').load" as someone on that thread suggested and icons did appear in IE11, but then the fill color of SVGs stopped changing on hover. SVGs are initially supposed to be light gray and change to the original color on hover, but now they are all colored according to the fill attribute that's set inside the original svg files.
Is there a way to fix this so that SVG's load properly in IE11 and to keep the hover fill color animation at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was no problem with the code or the plugin itself. The problem was that the svg files were missing doctype declaration.
I added `<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">` to svg files and now they load properly in IE11.